# Azure Linux remove and add another disk

Tags: linux, storage, azure

I had a need to increase the disk space, for my Linux azure, we attached a new empty disk and followed the steps here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk , the only difference is that the newly added deviceid was not found in /var/log/messages.

Now I need to add another disk, and we attached another disk, the problem is that for doing the first step of fdisk

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
```

I have no idea where the recent disk is attached, total clueless, also what are the steps if i want to remove a disk altogether, I know umount will unmount a disk, but that doesn't neccessarily takes off the device from the instance, i want a total detachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out - the additional SCSI disks added are started from /dev/sda, /dev/sdb , /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd, /dev/sde.... The reason why the MS tutorial talks about /dev/sdc is because its the 3rd disk in the system, 1st your root volume, second your ephemeral temp storage, and this is your 3rd one, now as the /dev/sdc is not good enough for you and you want to remove it

1. Remove entry from /etc/fstab file
2. umount /datadrive

you can now remove the attached disk from your Azure console.

Lets say that sdc is still there and you want to add another, just attach from the azure console, and do the same steps as given in http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk/#initializeinlinux  the only diff is that the another disk would be at /dev/sdd places where you make a partitions at /dev/sdc1 will become /dev/sdd1  that's pretty much about it.

References

1. http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdditionalHardDrive.html
2. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk/#initializeinlinux

Answer (score 0):

After attaching the new disk do the following from the CLI:

```
$ sudo grep SCSI /var/log/syslog      ##MAKE SURE sdc IS THERE
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc                   ##to create a new partition
```

- press n (to create new partition)
- press p (to make it primary)
- press 1 to make it 1st partition
- press p for details about it
- press w to write settings for disk and you're done

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1       #TO MAKE THE FILE SYSTEM ext4 (or 3)
$ sudo mkdir /datadrive ##(OR ANY OTHER NAME FOR YOUR NEW DRIVE)
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /datadrive
```

The last 2 commands are to make datadrive as the new mount for the sdc we created. To make the file system mounted automatically on restarts:

```
$ sudo -i blkid
```

Take the output of `sdc1` (ex. `/dev/sdc1: UUID="33333333-3b3b-3c3c-3d3d-3e3e3e3e3e3e" TYPE="ext4"`)

```
$ sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

Add this to the end:

```
UUID=33333333-3b3b-3c3c-3d3d-3e3e3e3e3e3e   /datadrive   ext4   defaults   1   2
```

To test if file system mounted properly:

```
$ sudo umount /datadrive
$ sudo mount /datadrive
```